# Integral of power and exponentials

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Everyone,

Could you help me on the following integral, Many thanks for your help!

$\int\limits_0^\infty  {{y^{v - 1}} \cdot \exp \left( { - p{y^a} - q{y^b}} \right)dy} $

where $p>0, q>0$, $a, b$, and $v$ are constant.

Comment: In the extremely narrow example of $a=b=1$ and $p+q=1$ then your integral evaluates to $\Gamma(v)$.

Comment: As a start: Wolfram Alpha gives a primitive for `int(x^a*exp(-b*x^c),x)` in terms of the incomplete Gamma function.

Answer (score 1):

> *Could you help me on the following integral ?*

The short answer is **no**. Giving various values to the two exponents *a* and *b*, we notice that the result yields completely different types of special functions each time $($ [$\Gamma$ functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), [Bessel functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function), [Airy functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function), [Anger functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anger_function), etc. $)$ – and this is only for $a,~b\le4.$ Beyond that, we have [hypergeometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) and [Meijer G-functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function), etc.